# Need to Group/Sort and then do operation in the same column

Tags: r

[image]1- For Each Part No, and also for each order Number ( need some grouping) , I need the data to be sorted in ascending order using the column On Time Start

2- Then I need to calculate the delta between two cells from the same column ( see picture bellow : B-A) , then create a new column called Span.plus.Queue

The reason I need to sort by ascending order is because the delta calculation must always be positive

```
structure(list(Order = c("100016572", "100016572", "100016572", 
"100049101", "100049101", "100049101", "100049101", "100049101", 
"100049101", "100049101"), Op = c(9997, 9997, 9997, 8391, 8392, 
8393, 8394, 8395, 8396, 8397), `Op Desc` = c("PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", 
"PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", "PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", 
"ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779", "MACHINE SHOP IAW 200365779", 
"ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779", "PP&C REWORK IAW 200365779", 
"INSPECT IAW 200365779", "ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779", "PP&C REWORK IAW 200365779"
), `Part No` = c("2352841G1-516", "2352841G1-516", "2352841G1-516", 
"2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", 
"2352841G1", "2352841G1"), WBS = c("G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", 
"G-CUST-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", 
"G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01"), `Work Cntr` = c("26801702", 
"26801702", "26801702", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", 
"CHRI0000", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000"), `On Time Start` = structure(c(1557852668.803, 
1557852668.803, 1557852668.803, 1579215738.477, 1579279874.08, 
1579598294.2, 1579625528.097, 1579690071.267, 1583883648.167, 
1584029686.74), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    `On Time Comp` = structure(c(1585156034.313, 1585156034.313, 
    1585156034.313, 1579216621.723, 1579285486.47, 1579605490.21, 
    1579626040.097, 1583876924.857, 1584012522.213, 1584029801.71
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Span_CDay = structure(c(316.011174884259, 
    316.011174884259, 316.011174884259, 0.0102227546302257, 0.0649582175938068, 
    0.0832871527776674, 0.00592592592592593, 48.4589535879647, 
    1.49159775462967, 0.00133067129662743), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), groups = structure(list(Order = c("100016572", "100049101"
), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Don't add `rstudio` tag for questions related to only R. `rstudio` tag is reserved for questions related to the RStudio IDE.

Comment: What is RStudio IDE/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you get what you want with this. Here, mydf is your data frame.

```
attach(mydf)
#Sort with ascending order
mydf[order(Order,`On Time Start`),]

#Add the new column for the delta and assigned NAs as initial values
mydf$Span.plus.Queue = NA_real_

#Compute the delta in days, and store the result in the new column
k = 1:nrow(mydf)
mydf$Span.plus.Queue[k]= ifelse(Order[k]== Order[k+1], difftime(`On Time Start`[k+1],`On Time Start`[k], unit = "days"), NA)
mydf

#  Order       Op `Op Desc`               `Part No`    WBS     `Work Cntr` `On Time Start`     `On Time Comp`      Span_CDay      Span.plus.Queue
   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>                   <chr>        <chr>   <chr>       <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>                   <dbl>
# 1 1000165~  9997 PP&C Movement / Go To ~ 2352841G1-5~ G-CUST~ 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 3.160112e+02 ~           0    
# 2 1000165~  9997 PP&C Movement / Go To ~ 2352841G1-5~ G-CUST~ 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 3.160112e+02 ~           0    
# 3 1000165~  9997 PP&C Movement / Go To ~ 2352841G1-5~ G-CUST~ 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 3.160112e+02 ~          NA    
# 4 1000491~  8391 ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 20~ 2352841G1    G-6M76~ CHRP0000    2020-01-16 23:02:18 2020-01-16 23:17:01 1.022275e-02 ~           0.742
# 5 1000491~  8392 MACHINE SHOP IAW 20036~ 2352841G1    G-6M76~ CHRP0000    2020-01-17 16:51:14 2020-01-17 18:24:46 6.495822e-02 ~           3.69 
# 6 1000491~  8393 ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 20~ 2352841G1    G-6M76~ CHRP0000    2020-01-21 09:18:14 2020-01-21 11:18:10 8.328715e-02 ~           0.315
# 7 1000491~  8394 PP&C REWORK IAW 200365~ 2352841G1    G-6M76~ CHRP0000    2020-01-21 16:52:08 2020-01-21 17:00:40 5.925926e-03 ~           0.747
# 8 1000491~  8395 INSPECT IAW 200365779   2352841G1    G-6M76~ CHRI0000    2020-01-22 10:47:51 2020-03-10 21:48:44 4.845895e+01 ~          48.5  
# 9 1000491~  8396 ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 20~ 2352841G1    G-6M76~ CHRP0000    2020-03-10 23:40:48 2020-03-12 11:28:42 1.491598e+00 ~           1.69 
# 10 1000491~  8397 PP&C REWORK IAW 200365~ 2352841G1    G-6M76~ CHRP0000    2020-03-12 16:14:46 2020-03-12 16:16:41 1.330671e-03 ~          NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
            arrange(Order, `On Time Start`) %>%
            group_by(Order) %>%
            mutate(Span.plus.Queue = as.numeric(difftime(lead(`On Time Start`), 
                             `On Time Start`, units = 'days')))
```

Comment: is making the calculation but the results are not in the right cells,  needs to be shifted up by one cell. See the picture.

Comment: The code ran, but the results need to be shifted up by one up. In the picture you can see it.  That is the only part i am missing

Comment: @JavierPrieto Can you check my updated answer.